# How would a homepage consisting only buttons directing users to what they need work?

Tags: surveys, homepage, progressive-disclosure

I'm building a homepage for an organization and here are some problem:

1. The organization has multiple projects that doesn't seem obviously relevant at first look
2. The needs of the users are various and impermanent
3. While the projects aim to solve those needs, at first look some projects' names might not seem obviously connected to the wording of the user's needs
4. People just skim reading website, until they do have time and motivation to fully understand it

I guess the solution should:

1. Only present tailored information for individual need
2. Use user's wording of their needs, not the solutions' names
3. Be really short

I come up with an idea that it's best to have separate homepages for each projects. The main homepage is just a survey question for what they need. Each answer, which is also a button, will bring them to the correct project's homepage (err, subhomepage?). This is basically [Progressive Disclosure](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/progressive-disclosure/).

Here is the [mockup](https://mydraft.cc/ch2mra95je2nd1j0q86g):

[image]

I do notice that I'm unable to find a single one website follows this idea. Are there some fundamental flaws in here? How would this idea work?

Answer (score 1):

Before studying what the problem is at the functional level, I know at the marketing level it's a big mistake.

Making someone enter to a website is like fishing and implies a great effort, where the network is an ocean and the Internet users are the fish. No one would let any fish escape for any reason. If it's a private company, no one would let any fish escape for any reason. If a user enters my website, whatever it may be, I would not lose even half a pixel in which they do not have some information about the content or function of my company.

There are several companies that have products for different sectors, and they usually have a corporate institutional landing page and the buttons of the corresponding sectors for the user to choose. An example is the landing page of the [Spanish tax agency](https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/) made up entirely of buttons with a brief explanation of the destination.

[image]

Comment: isn't this exactly the opposite of what progressive disclosure? Each individual user have their unique need. So except the product that serve their need, the rest are just fluff for them and they will ignore. By strictly limiting the text showing up, the users won't feel overload. Plus that we can always show more text when the users hover the button

Answer (score 1):

First - I like that you're thinking about jobs to be done, and using the user's language instead of the business' language. Those are two really good things for a homepage.

The reason you don't see button groups as desktop homepage content is because:

1. Some user tasks are frankly more important to the business - or are far more used by end users - than others.  "Buy our washing machine" is a more heavily weighted priority than "Sign up for our deals". Button groups give everything the same visual priority, more or less.
2. Users expect their most important tasks to be so obvious, that they don't have to read through every action on a page in order to take their next step. Imagine if the button group became eight labels... or twelve. The user has to read and digest every one. Cognitive load!
3. Good visual design conveys quality and trust. A lack of good visual design makes users wonder if they landed on the correct website, and if the business is legitimate.
4. Ever mistype a domain name, and a squatter's page comes up... and it's just a bunch of links or buttons, because they're selling affiliate traffic? I think most people associate a button-only homepage with this yucky pattern.

I do think this pattern is accepted on mobile, where users are far more task-oriented and have less data to burn on marketing images.

Comment: These points are reasonable. I think 4 is just an elaboration of 3. However, I guess there are businesses that wouldn't need to have 12 buttons. We can put less important links (e.g. "Login", "Search", "Contact", "Facebook/YouTube/Twitter", etc.) small and not as answers, and we can decorate the survey. For example, hovering a button will show more text and change the image next to it. I guess this will solve these concerns?

Comment: I think cards with a little more information that helps the user reinforce that they're going where they want to go - such as in @Danielillo 's example below - would be a better solve than disclosing info on hover. It can still be designed to look clean.

Comment: but would the simple act of explaining the items, even briefly, still create overload?

Comment: I wouldn't think so if you use a quick scannable headline and a subordinated description. https://www.microsoft.com/ is good at steering many different audiences to many different products on its homepage.